# Unidentified Name Error while using required.this value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So Iam trying to make a chat-app using Firebase-Firestore where you have an option of creating group. Now after creating a group Iam navigating to a screen from where you can add member. But for that I gonna need to pass the groupRoomId.

Here Iam navigating to add member screen:

```
 Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Add_Member(
              groupRoomId: groupRoomId,
            )));
```

Now here is my add member screen:

```
class Add_Member extends StatefulWidget {
  final String groupRoomId;
  Add_Member({required this.groupRoomId});
  _Add_Member createState() => _Add_Member();
}

class _Add_Member extends State<Add_Member> {
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? searchResultSnapshot;
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? Snapshot;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool haveUserSearched = false;
  bool isChecked = false;
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  var searchEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final DocumentReference <Map<String, dynamic>>? documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("groups/$groupRoomId");

addremovemember(userName){
    documentReference?.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot){
      if (datasnapshot.data()!.containsValue("$userName")){
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .doc('$groupRoomId')
            .update({"users" : FieldValue.arrayRemove(["$userName"])});
      }
      else{
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .doc('$groupRoomId')
            .update({"users" : FieldValue.arrayUnion(["$userName"])});
      }
    });
  }
......
```

So what is happening that in DocumentReference $groupRoomId is showing Unidentified Name Error.
My ultimate aim is to being able to add and remove error(in future too) as you may see in addremovemember function.
I would highly appreciable if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Davis is right.
You are referencing groupRoomId which is outside the build scope.

For this to work, access it using the `widget` keyword.

Replace `.doc('$groupRoomId')` with `.doc(widget.groupRoomId)`

You can access it like this:

```
class _Add_Member extends State<Add_Member> {
  ...
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');

  void addremovemember(userName) {
    collectionReference.doc(widget.groupId).snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.data()!.containsValue(userName)) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .doc(widget.groupId)
            .update({
          'users': FieldValue.arrayRemove([userName])
        });
      } else {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('groups')
            .doc(widget.groupId)
            .update({
          'users': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userName])
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is there any problem with this answer? OP said the DocumentReference is showing undefined name. This means that the variable groupRoomId is not defined. So, the error is not from Navigator.push as Davis suggested. Rather than re-writing Davis entire answer and explaining (so he can accept my answer), I write a fresh answer.

Comment: Your method works. However how can I add the groupRoomId when I 'am initializing the Firebase from FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("...")

Comment: Doesn't this work: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc(widget.groupRoomId)`?

Comment: NO it tells we cannot use instance member 'widget' as initialiser.

Comment: That error is because you are trying to access widget as an initialiser. I have updated my answer so you see how you can access the document.

Answer (score 0):

It happens so because you are referencing `groupRoomId` which is outside the build scope.

For this to work use the keyword `widget`

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Add_Member(
              groupRoomId: widget.groupRoomId,// <-here
            )));
```